# Qual a diferença entre as versões mostradas Flutter doctor e do Vscode?

Tags: flutter

O comando flutter doctor mostra:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows

Já no vscode mostra:
Flutter: 1.12.13+hotfix.9

Qual a diferença entre estas versões?

Answer (score 1):

Como atualizei pelo terminal do vscode ele não atualiza a descrição da versão automaticamente. Tive que reiniciar o vscode.